# Adding User Values to Two-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a program called Student Grades, which simulates a grade book for a class with 15 students who each have four test scores. I must use a two-dimensional array to store my data. I need to format my data like "Jeremy Folson, 85, 99, 33, 44". I am having trouble specifically with adding the different students to my array and displaying it properly. I understand that my adding function does not work because will add the same data 15 times. Can someone please explain how to make my code perform the desired task?

```
// Declare two-dimensional array
Object [][] grades = new Object [15][5]; 

private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
evt) {                                       

//Clear output area
txtaDisplay.setText(null);

// Declare variables
String firstName, lastName, name; 
int test1, test2, test3, test4;

firstName = txtFirstName.getText();
lastName = txtLastName.getText();
name = firstName + " " + lastName;

test1 = Integer.parseInt(txtTest1.getText());
test2 = Integer.parseInt(txtTest2.getText());
test3 = Integer.parseInt(txtTest3.getText());
test4 = Integer.parseInt(txtTest4.getText());

for(int i = 0; i < 15 ; i++){
    grades[i][0] = name;
    grades[i][1] = test1;
    grades[i][2] = test2;
    grades[i][3] = test3;
    grades[i][4] = test4;
    }
    }                                      

public void displayArray() {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
    for( int col=0; col < 5; col++) {
        sb.append(String.valueOf(grades[row][col]));
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
}
txtaDisplay.append(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your data structure conststing only of `Object` should be improved. A first draft would be:

```
class StudentEntry
{
    String name;
    Integer[] grade = new Integer[4];
}

List<StudentEntry> gradBook = new ArrayList<>();
```

Your main question was why the same combination was entered 15 times. This is due to the aspect that you only read once the input to `firstName`, ... and then assigned it in the for-loop to every row.
As we don't see when `btnAddActionPerformed` is called two possibilities:

a. Called each time a student is entered: Just create a new `StudentEntry` and add it to the `gradBook` (or if you stay with arrays: keep a counter how many students have already been added, e.g. a `static int`).

b. Called only when all student records have been entered: use a for-loop and read the next student data *inside* the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15 ; i++) {
    StudentEntry student = new StudentEntry();
    student.name = txtFirstName.getText() + " " + txtLastName.getText();
    ...
    studentBook.add(student);
}
```